# zxing decoding qrcode including vcard data: wrong field separation, etc

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing, vcf-vcard

Encoding a vCard with N and ADR and decoding it with Barcode Scanner 4.3.2 on Android (ICS 4.0.4) and adding it as a contact works very poorly: separated fields (separation by semi-columns like this N:Last;First;;;) in name and address are not preserved. Also URL is converted to 'Note'. What is the reason *no* Qr code scanner in Android preserves this.
BTW other QR scanners I tried (Qr Barcode, Qr Droid) behave even poorer: they don't respect TEL;WORK: TEL;MOBILE: ADR;WORK: (WORK replaced with home, etc).

I can still suspect some strict format or version in vCard that makes QR decoder to contact stutter in Android but I doubt.

For example I used goqr.me to encode this:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:2.1
FN:FN LN
N:LN;FN
TITLE:Title
TEL;CELL:+33666
TEL;WORK;VOICE:+33999
TEL;HOME;VOICE:+33000
EMAIL;HOME;INTERNET:home@home
EMAIL;WORK;INTERNET:work@work
URL:http://my.not
ADR:;;Street, Nb;City;;37000;Country
ORG:organz
END:VCARD
```

The result is acceptable on Barcode Scanner (though: no first name / last name separation and two space characters instead of one between them, no separations preserved in address and URL not decoded as such, but as a note). Forget about the other Android scanners mentioned above: all the inaccuracies already met with Barcod Scanner + wrong phone and address type, title ignored, url ignored...)

Is there no way to improve this? Where is the limitation/bottleneck: API for adding contacts, QR address book format and decoding limitations?

After many hours working and trying on ways to encode vCards in Qr Codes (just on Android) it seems to me this is conceptually half-baked. Did I miss something?
Thank you.